# JQuery Autocomplete populates all rows at select

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am having a problem with JQuery. I need to populate the `<input class="itemDescription">` after user selects an item from an autocomplete dropdown menu `<input class="itemCode">`. The JQuery works fine, only when user selects an `item` then both inputs on line 1 and line 2 are populated with the same Item Description. I think that the probelm is that both `itemDescription` inputs have the same class. However, I am not sure how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td >Item Code</td>            
        <td >Description</td>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td class=""><input class="itemCode"></td>            
       <td class=""><input class="itemDescription"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class=""><input class="itemCode"></td>            
      <td class=""><input class="itemDescription"></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>


<script>
  $( function() {
     $( ".itemCode" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax( {
          url: "item-search.php",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            term: request.term
          },
          success: function( data ) {
            response( data );
          }
        } );
      },
      minLength: 1,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
          $( ".itemDescription" ).val( ui.item.label );
       }
    } );
  } );
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference the correct input using the given context. Try the following:

```
$(this).parent().next().children(".itemDescription").val(ui.item.label);
```

If you want it to work for any field that you may add, use the following:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().children(".itemDescription").val(ui.item.label);
```

Comment: What the syntax should look like if I add an additional field for example `itemPrice`? If I try this: `$(this).parent().next().children(".itemDescription").val(ui.item.itemDescription);
       $(this).parent().next().children(".itemCost").val(ui.item.itemCost);`
Then the new field `itemPrice` is not populated. Thanks!

Comment: You can either add an extra `.next()` or use my edited solution. I would suggest my edited solution as it is more general.

Answer (score 0):

Try just addressing the result to the first instance of that class it finds.

```
$( ".itemDescription" ).val( ui.item.label );
```

will set all elements with that class as to that value.  If you want to only set the first one, use something like

```
$( ".itemDescription" ).first().val( ui.item.label );
```

Comment: I just changed it to `$( ".itemDescription" ).first().val( ui.item.label );` but now only the very first one is populated.

Comment: Should i use `this` instead?

Comment: you need to try to find a way in jQuery to get the index (position) of the 'current input field'   then use that index to target a specific description field

Comment: I wasn't sure what your data looked like.  If you want to iterate over your data, the code will look a little different. Can you add the data that's returned?

Comment: I just return data in Json format: `[{"value":"A001","label":"item1"},{"value":"A002","label":"Item2"}]`

Comment: Ok, so just to be clear, you want it to populate the first one, and if the first one is empty, populate the second one?